# What is the equivalent of the back arrow in pseudocode?

Tags: java

I am a new Java programming student and don't understand what the back arrow in "psuedocode" would mean in real code if I typed it in to a compiler.
Example: rectangleArea <--- length * width, what does it mean?

Comment: "Assign to", your example would read "assign length x width to rectangleArea"

Comment: Yes, but what would the syntax be?

Comment: That's what I would assume. However, since "pseudocode" is a class of representations rather than a specific representation, I would recommend checking with whoever has defined this particular pseudocode representation -- and/or with your instructor or TAs.

Comment: The backwards arrow used in many LaTeX algorithm packages is "\gets", as in "x \gets 5" rendered "x <- 5", which is probably what's going on here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that is supposed to be a representation of assignment, it would mean something like create a variable `rectangleArea` and assign the result of the multiplication of `length` and `width` to it. Or,

```
int rectangleArea = length * width;
```